# Simple past vs past progressive in as/while-clauses

Tags: tense

> As/while I **was walking** along the beach, I saw a UFO.

In that sentence, what difference does it make if the past progressive verb is replaced with a simple past?

> As/while I **walked** along the beach, I saw a UFO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example it makes no difference, because both *as* and *while* constrain an [**imperfective**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) reading of the verb. That is, even though past-form *walked* is ordinarily understood as perfective (not 'perfect'), a completed action, use with *as* or *while* forces it to be understood as an activity in progress.

With *when*, however, it might make a difference, depending on whether the verb in the *when* clause is telic or atelic—has or does not have a final change of state ‘built in’ to its meaning. The verb in your *when* clause is atelic, so again it makes no difference in your example. But if the verb is telic—*leave*, for instance, which involves a change of location—it does make a difference.

- With a telic verb, the past form is understood as perfective in a *when* clause; in that case, the action in the main verb will be understood to to occur **after** the completed action in the *when* clause:

  > When I left the beach, I saw a UFO.
- But if the verb in the *when* clause is atelic, or if it is a telic verb cast in the progressive form (which ‘stativizes’ it), it is understood as imperfective, an action in progress, and the action in the main clause will be understood to occur **during** the non-completed action in the *when* clause:

  > When I was leaving the beach, I saw a UFO.